# Java 'has-a' relationship explanation

Tags: java, oracle

I was reviewing some sample questions for the java certified professional exam, and wanted to get some clarity on the answer to one of the questions:

```
2. Given:

class Class1 {
String v1;
}
class Class2 {
Class1 c1;
String v2;
}
public class Class3 {
Class2 c1;
String i3;
}

Which three options correctly describe the relationship between the classes?
A) Class2 has-a i3
B) Class1 has-a v2
C) Class2 has-a v2
D) Class3 has-a v1
E) Class2 has-a Class3
F) Class2 has-a Class1
```

The answer provided is: C,D, and F

I get why C and F are correct, but I'm not so sure about D.

My understanding of the 'has-a' relationship as it pertains to the object-oriented context, is that if 'A has a Z', that means that Class A either has a member variable(or attribute as it is called sometimes) called Z (or of type Z), OR, the same is true via inheritance, meaning if Class A extends Class B, and Class B has a Z, then it is correct to say that Class A has a Z as well (through inheritance).

From what I see, Class3 has c1 and has a i3, and since Class3 doesn't extend any classes, that is where the 'has-a' relationship ends.

I see that Class3 has a Class2, and Class2 has a Class1, and Class1 has a v1, but I didn't realize that meant that Class3 has a v1, seems to me that Class1 has a v1.

This is straight from the Oracle website:

http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=303&p_certName=SQ1Z0_804

Answer (score 1):

Class3 has a Class2 called c1 which has a Class1 called c1 which has a String called v1

so Class3 has a v1:  `Class3.c1.c1.v1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess sometime reading your own question helps. It makes since in a car example. A Car has an Engine, an Engine has a Piston, therefore a Car has a Piston. Just seems strange in the object oriented world, my understanding was off. I think I get it now.

Comment: I feel useless XD

Answer (score 0):

A **has-a** relationship is used for object containment. containment means, an object contains another object. It can also be termed as **composition**.

For example: A car has a music system, the music system has a speaker. Hence, the car has a speaker.

'has-a' relationship occurs If a class have an entity reference. I.e, Aggregation.

**The option D is correct because**, Class3 contains entity reference of Class2 and Class2 contains entity reference of Class1.

Hence, objects of Class3 has properties of Class2, as Class2 objects has properties of Class1, Class3 has a relationship with Class1 called as 'aggregation/has-a'.

Class1 has a v1, means objects of Class3 contains property value of v1.